# Best way to duplicate/sync private database with FA2 contract transactions & balances

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, dapps, fa2, database

If you wanted a private DB to have all of the transactions,balances etc. of a particular FA2 contract deployed on mainnet, what would be the best way of achieving this?

Is it possible to have a callback API that gets triggered every time a transaction/contract function is made/called (via oracles)? Or possible to use a block explorer to watch for updates to the contract? Any other method?

Keen to hear thoughts!

Answer (score 1):

tzkt.io offers a websocket based listener that can be used for the scenario mentioned by you.

Alternatively, you can run a cron job that checks for changes in the contract storage (tzkt's API can be used once again) and records the same in the DB.

Comment: Anshu - thanks for that, looking into this :)